# Uniformly distributed points in 2D

Tags: matlab, uniform

How I can generate uniformly distributed points in two dimensions?
I tested this code, but I do not want this because in this code `x` and `y` are uniform, but the pairs of `(x,y)` are not uniform.

```
X=rand(2,N);
x= X(1,:);
y=X(2,:);
figure;                                     
plot(x,y,'.');
```

Comment: why `(x,y)` are not uniform?

Comment: how i can load an image? i run this code and i see points are not uniform

Comment: you can upload an image to [imgur](http://imgur.com/upload) and post a link to the image here.

Comment: what is `N`? for small `N` the data might **appear** non-uniform due to sampling effects, but as `N-->\inf` `(x,y)` are uniformly distributed over the `[0,1]x[0,1]` domain.

Comment: in my code N=50

Comment: Try increasing N then, and you will see that points are actually uniform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does uniformly sample the 2D space. But there is also the `unifrnd` method in Matlab, that samples n-D space.

```
N = 5000;
rng(320);
X=rand(2,N);
x=X(1,:);
y=X(2,:);
figure('Position',[125 125 1200 500]);                                     
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(x,y,'.');  

rng(320);
X2 = unifrnd(0,1,2,N);
x=X(1,:);
y=X(2,:);
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(x,y,'.');
```

[image: Comparison of methods]

Comment: If an error appears is probably because your random number generator is the legacy generator. Try running `rng('default')` at the beginning of the code.

Comment: If you type `edit unifrnd` you can learn that `unifrnd` calls `rand` under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

The [`scatterhist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/scatterhist.html) function is useful for visualizing marginal distributions along with the correlation structure. Image and code below (using @FranzHahn's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41040591/8239061)).

[image: Scatterhist]

```
N = 5000;
rng(320);
X=rand(2,N);
x=X(1,:);
y=X(2,:);
figure('Position',[125 125 1200 500]);                                     
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(x,y,'.');  

scatterhist(x,y,'Direction','out')
```